# Invoke a c# method of a class from external react script

Tags: unity-game-engine

EDIT: Problem solved - The `SendMessage` method is available on `window.gameInstance`.

Please pardon my ignorance, I am just beginning to experiment with Unity and c# and I'm having a hard time finding valid information pertaining to this topic.

In Unity3d's documentation for [WebGL: Interacting with browser scripting](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html) - Calling Unity scripts functions from JavaScript; It instructs you to use `SendMessage(objectName, methodName, value);`. That is all well and good, but where is this `SendMessage` function found? It certainly isn't on the `window` object.

I know there is a `SendMessage` method of `GameObjects` but I'm trying to interact with Unity3d from outside of Unity3d so that isn't very useful.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Unity script creates a `gameInstance` object on the `window` object. You can access the `SendMethod` method through the `gameInstance`.

`window.gameInstance.SendMessage(objectName, methodName, value);`